# method injection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been reading about service containers
but I have a question about method injection
Laravel has its limits regarding method injection
as far as I know, we can only use method injection inside 3 methods (places)
first, all public methods inside the constructor
second, boot method inside any service provided,
third, handle method inside queue jobs
are there any other methods we can use method injection inside?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers ; 

public function store(request $request,User $user) {
   dd($user) //it works 
}
```

and also works inside boot method inside service provider and inside Laravel queue jobs, are there any methods?

Comment: I think you need a middleware

Comment: middleware uses constructor injection as far as i know , but here i am speaking about method injection

Comment: Injection will work in every place you want.. but if you have other plans for your injection you need to declare it on your service provider so when you resolve it laravel will know how to resolve it